# How can I process a table without headers in SpecFlow?

Tags: c#, .net, ruby, specflow, gherkin

Coming from using Gherkin in Ruby, I want to see if SpecFlow on C# .NET is an option for me. In Ruby I was able to process a table that has the fields in the first column and the values in the second, like this:

```
Then I see a summary of details in the overview page
| Service           | Taxi        |
| Arrival Station   | Middlebourg |
| Arrival Vehicle   | SAT12901    |
| Arrival Date      | 27/06/2014  |
| No of Passengers  | 2           |
```

Within SpecFlow I can use the TechTalk.SpeclFlow.Table object which has these functions:

- CreateInstance : Assumes that "Service" and "Taxi" are headings which they're not.
- CreateSet : Also ignores first line and returns key/value pairs. Also not working.

Of course a work around here is to change the layout of my table to match the working of SpecFlow's table object. But is there an alternative, like the "rows_hash" function in Ruby? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that SpecFlow always assumes a header.  You can access this header with:

```
table.Header
```

to get raw access to the headings. This is just a collection of strings so you can access the individual elements with:

```
var firstRowFirstColumn = table.Header[0];
var firstRowSecondColumn = table.Header[1];
```

You can then just access the remaining individual rows in the table with something like this:

```
foreach(var row in table.Rows)
{
   var first = row[0];
   var second = row[1];
   ... use the values ...
}
```

to get all of the other values in the table

if you want raw access without the headers I would create an extension method like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<TableRow> AllRows(this Table table)
{
     yield return new TableRow(table, table.Header);
     foreach(var row in table.Rows)
     {
         yield return row;
     }
 }
```

I don't know if you can create a `TableRow` (it looks like it should be possible from the source) like that and you might have to create your own `TableRow` object which wraps the specflow `TableRow` but you should get the idea.

Comment: Thanks Sam! This in fact works partially. The Rows property skips the first line of the table assuming it's the header. The first row in the foreach would return the columns "Arrival Station" and "Middlebourg". I can use table.Heading to get to "Service" & "Taxi".

Comment: Cool, glad it helped you towards a solution. I'll update the answer to include the information you provided

Comment: Thanks! Marked it as accepted answer. A rock-solid solution seems to simply insert "| field | value |" in the table.

Comment: Added an extension method which should give you what you want without having to add column headers. It's untested and might need some tweaking but should be in the right direction I think.